# How to align Chart.JS line chart labels to the center

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I'm using Chart.JS 1.0.2 to create a line chart:
[image: The chart I'm getting right now]

What I'm trying to do is move the labels that are on the bottom of the chart the center of each rectangle (instead of being aligned with the vertical grid lines):

[image: What I'm trying to get to]

There is no documentation about this on [chartjs.org](http://chartjs.org) but I believe that with a smart trick this problem can be easily solved. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

offsetGridLines (boolean)
If true, labels are shifted to be between grid lines.

```
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    ...
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true
            }
        ]}
    }
}
```

Comment: You gave the same answer as Pasqual. This solution is for Chart.js 2.0 while I'm working with Chart.js 1.

Comment: I didn't change param in code sorry... Now it's edited. I'm using offsetGridLines instead of drawOnChartArea. Does it work now?

Comment: I still don't think this is Chart.js 1.x syntax. The current syntax I have is:            `new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true,
    animation: true,
    pointDot: true,
    pointDotRadius: 5,
    bezierCurve: true,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 60,
    datasetStroke: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 4,
    datasetFill: true,
    barDatasetSpacing: 1,
    scaleOverride: true,
    drawOnChartArea: true,
    scaleSteps: 4,
    scaleStartValue: 0
});`

Comment: Wrong ! This parameter don't shift labels but GRIDLINES. It's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
labelOffset:-5 //adjust number
```

Comment: If you want to propose debugging experiments please use a comment. Though https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead If this is not a proposed experiment and is meant to be an actual answer please [edit] according to [answer]. Especially explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In [ChartJS Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration), under "Grid line Configuration" there is the drawOnChartArea option:

> Name: drawOnChartArea
>   Type: boolean
>   Description: If true, draw lines on the chart area inside the axis lines. This is useful when there are multiple axes and you need to control which grid lines are drawn

```
{
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        ...
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    drawOnChartArea: true
                }
            ]}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a small explanation to your answer to describe why this works.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Pasquale I think this solution is for chart.js 2.x while as I stated in my question, I am using chart.js 1.0.2. I tried to add `drawOnChartArea: true` to my chart options but that didn't help.

Comment: This does not seem to solve the question at all, does it? How does putting the lines in the chart area center the tick labels?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but hopefully helps someone.

My issue was trying to force a chart with `type: 'bubble'` and an x axis with `type: 'linear'` to place the labels in the center of the grid lines. The "centering the label" functionality comes standard for an axis with `type: 'category'`, like on bar charts. You can get linear point placement with category style labels by having two `xAxes` defined and not displaying the linear one.

In this example, points are plotted across a full 365 days, with x axis ticks for each quarter and the quarter label centered within its section of the plot.

```
data: {
    xLabels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
    ...
}, 
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                id: 'xAxis1',
                type: 'linear',
                display: false,
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 365,
                    stepSize: 365 / 4
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'xAxis2',
                type: 'category',
                gridLines: {
                    offsetGridLines: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Day of Year'
                }
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

I've used this for chart.js 2.x.